# Scope problem: moved function now doesn't find variable

Tags: javascript, function

I am working on a hybrid app (just for my own) with Framework7 and almost everything is working fine. I want to tidy up the code and move some repeating code into a function. But now I get the error

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: resolve

I am just learning JS and had the last couple days learned more about scope and context, but I can't figure out why I get this error. As I understand, as the resolve() callback function is defined in outer scope, I must be able to call it from my custom function?

When I put the app.request() where my getJson() function is, it works. However, the request still works from within getJson() and I can see the data logged, but the resolve function won't work as expected.

```
routes = [
    {
        path: '/person/abc/',
        async: function (routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
            var router = this;
            var app = router.app;
            var jwt = store.get('jwt');
            app.preloader.show();
            getJson(
                jwt,
                {document:'person'},
                'Test',
                '-/-'
            );

        },
    },
];


function getJson(jwt, data, title, note) {
    app.request({
        url:            'https://example.com/json/',
        method:         'GET',
        dataType:       'json',
        crossDomain:    true,
        data:           { data },
        headers:        { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + jwt },
        success: function(data, textStatus){
            if (data.status === 'ALLOW') {
                console.log('Data received');
                resolve(
                    {
                        componentUrl: './pages/person.html',
                    },
                    {
                        context: {
                            title: title, note: note, person: data.person,
                        }
                    }
                );
            } else {
                app.dialog.alert('Error loading data');
            }
            app.preloader.hide();
            return;
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('Error', xhr.response);
            app.preloader.hide();
            app.dialog.alert('Error on request');
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try passing `resolve` to `getJson`

Comment: You should *never* pass around `resolve` and `reject` of a `Promise` executor around as callbacks.

Comment: It works passing resolve into my function. But if I should never do it, how I am supposed to? I have about 12 routes, and all have almost the exact same code, but the Titel and the 'data' is different. I thought never to repeat my code?

Comment: Nobody can help?